# Difference between "Intrigued With" and "Intrigued By"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

What exactly is the difference between the usage of ***"intrigued with"*** and ***"intrigued by"*** in sentences?

Comment: Not much. . . .

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intrigued) has examples with "with" and "about". "By" often implies agency, while "with" makes the thing seem more passive, but I agree there's not much practical difference.